# Select some checkboxes based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have three checkbox button. I want it to function like this, when I click on select all, all checkboxes want to be selected, when I click on check companies, only companies need to be checked, when I select on freelancers only freelancers checkbox want to be selected.

Now first checkbox is working fine, all check boxes are getting selected and unselected, but other two are not working.

```js
$('#check_all').on("click", function(){
  var cbxs = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
  cbxs.prop("checked", !cbxs.prop("checked"));
});  
 

$('#mycompanies').click(function(){
        var select_all = (this.value === 'Select All');
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', select_all);
        this.value = (select_all) ? 'Deselect All' : 'Select All';        
    });
 $('#myfreelancers').click(function(){
        var select_all = (this.value === 'Select All');
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', select_all);
        this.value = (select_all) ? 'Deselect All' : 'Select All';        
    });
```

```html
<button type="button" id="check_all" class="btw">Check all/Uncheck all</button>
<button type="button" id="mycompanies"  class="mycompanies">Check all companies</button> 
<button type="button" id="myfreelancers" class="myfreelancers">Check all freelancers</button>
```

Here is my checkbox tag for freelancers:

```
 <% @m_freelancers.each do |freelancer| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%=check_box_tag 'selected_freelancers[]', freelancer.id%>
          
            <td><%= freelancer.email %></td>
<tr/>
        <% end %>
```

Checkbox for companies:

```
<% @m_companies.each do |company| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%=check_box_tag 'selected_companies[]', company.id%></td>
          
            <td><%= company.user.email %></td>
        
       </tr>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: From your snippet I can see the click function of your check_all button only. Where are your other pieces of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selector `[name="myElementName"]` to find your elements by name, and check them accordingly. Because your elements are HTML "arrays" (the `[]`), you'll need to include that in the selector as well.

You might want to consider using a class for this instead, might be a bit cleaner - but this selector will do just fine.

```js
// Check all if all is unchecked - remove all checks if one or more is checked
$('#check_all').on("click", function(){
    var cbxs = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    cbxs.prop("checked", !cbxs.prop("checked"));
}); 

$("#mycompanies").on("click", function() {
    var companyCheckboxes = $('[name="companies[]"]');
    companyCheckboxes.prop("checked", true);
});

$("#myfreelancers").on("click", function() {
    var freelancerCheckboxes = $('[name="freelancers[]"]');
    freelancerCheckboxes.prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="check_all" class="btw">Check all/Uncheck all</button>
<button type="button" id="mycompanies"  class="mycompanies">Check all companies</button> 
<button type="button" id="myfreelancers" class="myfreelancers">Check all freelancers</button>
<br />
<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="freelancers[]" /> Freelance 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="freelancers[]" /> Freelance 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="freelancers[]" /> Freelance 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="freelancers[]" /> Freelance 4<br />


<input type="checkbox" name="companies[]" /> Company 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companies[]" /> Company 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companies[]" /> Company 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companies[]" /> Company 4
```